# Horizontally align image and javascript rotating image in banner

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to include a javascript rotating image in the banner area. I cannot figure out how to get the image to display to the right of the logo, instead of underneath it. Here is what the code looks like when it displays the two images vertically aligned:

```
    <style>
<!--
A           { color: #000000; text-decoration: none; }
A:link      { color: #313131; text-decoration: none; }
A:visited   { color: #313131; text-decoration: none; }
A:active    { color: #C0C0C0;  }
A:hover     { color: #FF0000 ;  }

BODY,TD,TR{
    font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}
.banner {
    font-family: georgia, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    color:white;
    font-size:x-large;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-left:1px solid #FFF;
    border-right:1px solid #FFF;
    border-top:1px solid #FFF;
    background:#C0C0C0;
    padding:7px;
}
.description{
    font-family:verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:x-small;
    font-weight:bold;
}
//-->
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<div style="width: 700px; margin: 0 auto;" align="center">

<table border="0" width="700" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="banner"> <span class="description"><img style="width: 365px; height: 145px;"
                  title="Metamora Herald" alt="Metamora Herald" src="redbirdheraldlogo.png"></span><script type="text/javascript">
        show_banners();
    </script> </td>
    </tr>
```

How can I get the random image from the script to display to the right of the banner, not beneath it? Thanks

Comment: can you prepare a working code here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I attempted to get the code working there, but I am unsure of jsfiddle as this is my first experience with it. Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/m3FHJ/1/ and the site is here: http://www.mtco.com/~zmes420/metamora/germantown-hills/illinois/new/metamora/herald/online/example2.php

Comment: is that image beneath dynamic or just a GIF format image? And do you want that image to the right of that grey colored box?

Answer (score 0):

here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/SL9Kx/1/. Is that what you want?

i have changed the html code of your website's banner a little bit. you can ask about your query below (in comments), if any.

```
  /////
```

Comment: Thanks, but the image is dynamic based on the javascript and this doesn't look like the desired outcome. The banner should look like this page, with the 150x150 ad on the right of the grey box. http://www.mtco.com/~zmes420/metamora/germantown-hills/illinois/new/metamora/herald/online/biz.php